# Spring boot: resource [/src/main/resources/datadump.sql] defined by 'spring.datasource.data' does not exist

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, h2

Trying to load initial data into my h2 database. I have the sql file in the src/main/resources but it doesnt seem to be picking it up? It is in the same directory as my application-test.properties.

application-test.properties

```
#configuration for main data source
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
  spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
  hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
spring.datasource.data=src/main/resources/datadump.sql
```

Comment: It is still the same error

Comment: Try to use `spring.datasource.data=classpath:datadump.sql` instead. And you may need to add `spring.datasource.initialize=true` in your properties file.